# SQL join 2 times same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a flight table like

```
CREATE TABLE flight (id int, name varchar(25), origin int, destination int);
INSERT INTO flight (id, name, origin, destination) VALUES (1, 'Alpha', 1,2);
INSERT INTO flight (id, name, origin, destination) VALUES (2, 'Beta', 3,4);
...
```

And airport table like

```
CREATE TABLE airport (id int, name varchar(25));
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Amsterdam');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (2, 'London');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO airport (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Dubai');
...
```

How can I get all airports that made a flight to or brought in a flight from Amsterdam?

If I have a query with the where clause `WHERE flight.origin = 1 OR flight.destination = 1`
I also get Amsterdam in my results, while there is no flight from Amsterdam to Amsterdam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IN` clause:

```
select *
from airport
where id in (select origin from flight where destination = 1)
   or id in (select destination from flight where origin = 1);
```

Or

```
select *
from airport
where id in 
(
  select origin from flight where destination = 1
  union all
  select destination from flight where origin = 1
);
```

(You can of course replace `= 1` with `= (select id from airport where name = 'Amsterdam')`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
select a.* from airport a
where a.id <> 1
and exists (
  select 1 from flight f
  where a.id in (f.origin, f.destination) and 1 in (f.origin, f.destination)
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9be2b49e83524065e6367bbb2cae9025).
Results:

```
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  2 | London
```